# Kendo chart legend series style

Tags: javascript, css, charts, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo Chart with two or more series.
When the user click over a series name in the legend, this is hidden from the chart, and the series name in the legend change its color to a lighter blue.

The problem is that is not very intuitive that the series is disabled, 
and I'd like to **make it italic or change its color.**

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the solution. Easier than expected:

```
<div id="chart"></div>
<script>
$("#chart").kendoChart({
   legend: {
   inactiveItems: {
   labels: {
       color: "#aa00bb"
   }
}
},
  series: [
    { name: "Series 1", data: [1, 2, 3] },
    { name: "Series 2", data: [3, 4, 5] }
  ]
});
</script>
```